# Evaluating a search engine with unsupervised click logs

Tags: machine-learning, search-engine, information-retrieval, data-science

I have logs of users searching on my website and which searches they typed, and which results they clicked on. I would like to improve the search algorithm. But first I need a way of measuring its quality.

I am aware that I can collect data with Amazon Turk etc and get humans to produce a test suite. However I would like to use the data already available in my website logs.

Can anyone point me towards how I could do this please and which algorithm to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a big topic often using an online evaluation technique called Interleaving. Do you only have your webserver logs, or do you also create custom search logs? Google Analytics?

For good introductory overview of system-centered evaluation of search engines with pointers to other work on this topic, see the slides of Mounia Lalmas: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/mounialalmas/an-introduction-to-systemoriented-evaluation-in-information-retrieval

I think for practical purposes, you could check out this post by Daniel Tunkelang: 
http://twiggle.com/blog/evaluating-good-search-part-ii-measuring-searcher-behavior?utm_content=59131694

You could check out the positions of the first clicked results (Mean Recipopal Rank), or if that's too much work to reconstruct, simply the number of clicks would be a good start. This gives you a baseline. And given your domain and how your application is setup, you could check out how often an action (booked, bought, contacted, etc)  is taken after a click (conversion rate). If your website has some traffic, you could do some A/B testing to which ones results in a higher click rate and/or conversion rates.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try both of these